# Cross compilation project Yocto libz.so file not recognized

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, yocto

I encountered a problem when trying make a cross compilation using arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-g++ , the problem is the follow:

Log error

```
/home/.../libz.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
```

My makefile contains the path to the correct directory that contains the cited file, anybody have an suggestion that how can i fix it?

**EDIT1**

Running the command "file" on the file, the system return the follow result:

```
->file libz.so
->libz.so: symbolic link to `libz.so.1.2.7'
```

**EDIT2**

And executing on libz.so.1.2.7

```
->file libz.so.1.2.7
->libz.so.1.2.7: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=0xc8ddf1808db4d41de52cea35bf10f6a8416ac42d, not stripped
```

**EDIT3**

The full error:

```
Building target: SAT
Invoking: Cross GCC Linker
arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc -L/home/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib -L/home/prjs/.../build/tmp/sysroots/imx28evk/usr/lib/ -L/home/prjs/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/include -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lcurl -o "SAT"  ./src/prj/appSat.o ./src/prj/srvAc.o ./src/prj/srvFisco.o ./src/prj/srvLeds.o  ./src/api/soapFiles/soapC.o ./src/api/soapFiles/soapClient.o ./src/api/soapFiles/stdsoap2.o  ./src/api/apiAcParse.o ./src/api/apiAddTagsSATToCF.o ./src/api/apiAtivaSat.o ./src/api/apiBloqueio.o ./src/api/apiCallBack.o ./src/api/apiCfeComandos.o ./src/api/apiConfiguracoes.o ./src/api/apiEvent.o ./src/api/apiFiscoRequests.o ./src/api/apiFiscoUtils.o ./src/api/apiGPIO.o ./src/api/apiGeraComandosXML.o ./src/api/apiLanConfig.o ./src/api/apiMsg.o ./src/api/apiNvRam.o ./src/api/apiOutrosSat.o ./src/api/apiParametrizacao.o ./src/api/apiSeguranca.o ./src/api/apiSerial.o ./src/api/apiSignature.o ./src/api/apiThread.o ./src/api/apiTimer.o ./src/api/apiUtils.o ./src/api/apiValidaCF.o ./src/api/apiValidaUtils.o ./src/api/apiVendasSat.o ./src/api/apiWatchDog.o ./src/api/apiXSDValidation.o ./src/api/apiXmlUtils.o ./src/api/sha2.o ./src/api/strptime.o  ./src/SAT.o   -lpthread -lz -lgnutls -lgpg-error -lcap -ltasn1 -lcrypto -lssl -lgcrypt -lcurl -lxml2
/home/.../sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/libexec/armv5te-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/4.7.2/ld: warning: library search path "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu" is unsafe for cross-compilation
/home/prjs/.../build/tmp/sysroots/x86_64-linux/usr/lib/libz.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [SAT] Error 1
```

Comment: No, you need to supply more info. Eg the exact error message. You could also run `file` in that file to show us what it is.

Comment: The question was updated.

Comment: How about `file libz.so.1.2.7`?

Comment: Updated running above libz.so.1.2.7

Comment: And the full error, as well as the command that gives the error (can to compiler, linker, etc). more that you say that you're cross-compiling, but the libz.so that isn't recognised is on the x86_64 sysroot... Which your second run of `file` tells us. It's not for your arm platform, but for your host.

Comment: Why are your makefile / recipe mixing library paths from birth the target sysroot and your host sysroot? If you can't find out why, you need to die is your recipe and makefile